# Combine column based on condition by keeping other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have input dataframe that has 7columns and more than 800k rows
i need to apply filters only for the column ID and Band

```
    ID      Band    
|--------|-------|
    A11     1800  
    A18     1800  
    B11     1800  
    B18     1800  
    B21     2400
    C11     1800 
    C18     1800  
    2       2100    
    3       2100        
    A1      2100        
    A2      2100
    A16     2300
    A11     1800        
    A18     1800        
    A26     2600        
    A27     2600 
    9       800
```

I need output as

```
  ID        Band
|--------|--------| 
 A11,A18    1800  
 B11,B18    1800 
 B21        2400
 C11,C18    1800  
 2          2100        
 3          2100    
 A1,A2      2100
 A16        2300 
 A11,A18    1800  
 A26,A27    2600 
 9          800
```

Here i combine ID values if the Band has same values with conditions as follows.
i am checking row by row if same values found in Band column then i check ID column if it has numbers i do not touch that entire row, If alphabets i group them as A values separately, B values separately, C values separately ...etc, So i can get the data for same ban values in my dataframe that has 7 columns and more than 800k rows.
how can i achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the Name_ID column will be the same throughout the group? If not which Name_ID should be used?

Comment: Name_ID can be ignored, Mainly it is based on Rate we need to merge ID column by ignoring numbers and group based on alphabetics

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh*´, which most of the world does not use or understand.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
# Extract the alphabets from start of each string in ID column
# Note: For the rows having only numbers there will be None in the series `s`
s = df['ID'].str.extract(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)

# group the dataframe and aggregate ID with join
# Note: This will automatically ignore the rows having numbers while joining
df_agg = df.groupby(['Name_ID', 'Rate', s], as_index=False)['ID'].agg(', '.join)

# Concate the aggregated df with the rows having only numbers in the ID column
result = pd.concat([df_agg, df[s.isna()]]).sort_values(['Name_ID', 'Rate'], ignore_index=True)
```

##### Result

```
   Name_ID  Rate        ID
0  1356757  1800  A11, A18
1  1356757  2100    A1, A2
2  1356757  2100         2
3  1356757  2100         3
4  1356757  2600  A26, A27
5  1553877  1800  A11, A18
6  1553877  1800  B11, B18
7  1553877  1800  C11, C18
```

Comment: You might also consider filling the missing values in `s` with `fillna` like `df['ID'].str.extract(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False).fillna(df['ID'])` then you don't have to `concat` afterwards (Assuming, of course, that it'd be acceptable to group similar numbers together rather than requiring non-alphabetic IDs to be in distinct rows).

Comment: Yes, that'll also work assuming you have distinct numbers within each group..

Comment: While executing this code i am losing other columns in my data. What might be the issue

Comment: is there a way to apply this logic to the data where it has more columns and rows. For my data i have 7 columns and 7lakhs of rows. i want to combine ID values based on Rate and after combining remove duplicate rows only by keeping other columns as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use the groupby method in pandas and apply a custom aggregation function. Here's a code example that demonstrates how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the input DataFrame
data = {
   'Name_ID': [1553877, 1553877, 1553877, 1553877, 1553877, 1553877, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757, 1356757],
'ID': ['A11', 'A18', 'B11', 'B18', 'C11', 'C18', '2', '3', 'A1', 'A2', 'A11', 'A18', 'A26', 'A27'],
'Rate': [1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 2100, 2100, 2100, 2100, 1800, 1800, 2600, 2600]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Custom aggregation function
def aggregate_ids(ids):
    # Extract only alphabetical characters from the IDs
    alphabetic_ids = [id for id in ids if id.isalpha()]

    # Join the alphabetical IDs with commas
    combined_ids = ','.join(alphabetic_ids)

    return combined_ids

# Apply the groupby and aggregation
    grouped_df = df.groupby(['Name_ID', 'Rate'])
```

['ID'].agg(aggregate_ids).reset_index()

## Display the output DataFrame

print(grouped_df)